# Ranging multiplt ibeacon regions

Tags: ios, react-native, ibeacon, beacon

Iam using react-native-beacons-manager library in react native to discover ibeacon beacons, but when I add two const region1 and const region2 and then use Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region1) and Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region2)  it does not return anything.

The code I've used is

```
componentWillMount() {
    Beacons.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
    const region = {
      identifier: '973d0a2cf8f07443acdc71fad3df043d',
      uuid: 'B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D',
      major: 1,
      minor: 2
    };
    const region2 = {
      identifier: '39120dc19aa1a49c16b48bc4a5ea300b',
      uuid: '5627DB35-B8A3-4EDC-987C-462CCB3B034F',
      major: 2,
      minor: 1
    }
    // Range for beacons inside the region
    Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region2);
    Beacons.startUpdatingLocation();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Ranging: Listen for beacon changes
    this.beaconsDidRange = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
      'beaconsDidRange',
      (data) => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data.beacons)
        });
      }
    );
    const UniqueID = DeviceInfo.getUniqueID();


  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
    this.beaconsDidRange = null;
  }
```

Comment: I don't know anything about react native, but I can say with certainty that iOS is able to support ranging up to 20 beacon regions at a time (more precisely, up to 20 regions total, counting beacon regions and geofence regions together.) Post your code that creates the beacons, sets up monitoring, etc. You have to ask the user permission before beacon monitoring works, and you need 1 or 2 entries in your info.plist before you can request location info from the user.

Comment: You can't call `Beacons.requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and then immediately start setting up beacons. You have to make the call and then wait for the user to agree. There is a location manager delegate call `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)` that will be called if the user agrees. I suggest you find a demo app using beacons in react native and study that. There are a number of moving parts that you have to get right before this stuff works.

Comment: Again, I'm telling you how it works in native iOS. I don't know anything about React Native.

Comment: Thanks but I tried this code for a single region and it seems to work fine and fetches all permissions needed but when multiple regions are introduced it does not work!